# Notifications keep posting to slack channel

Tags: python, airflow, slack

I am using slack webhooks to send message to my slack channel.
The problem it keeps posting messages every few mins.
Here what I did...

I created a simple function under util folder.

```
def send_to_slack(text):
    conn_id = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/your/slack/URL"    
    task_slack_alert(text, url, is_error=False, args=None)

def task_slack_alert(msg, url, is_error=False, args=None):
     slack_msg = ":red_circle: Task Failed" if is_error else ":green_heart: Task Message"
     """*Task*: {task}  
        *Dag*: {dag} 
        *Execution Time*: {exec_ts}""".format(
                                          task=args["task"],
                                          dag=args["dag"],
                                          exec_ts=args["ts"],
        ) if args else ""
        message = {'text': + msg}
        response = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(message))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f"Slack response {response}")
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(f"Error sending chat message. Got: {response.status_code}")
```

In my dag (which is under another folder) I call the function
The dag copy data from oracle to snowflake db and this works without slack part.
Inside my dag i do the following:

```
 x = {‘key1’: [‘value1’, ‘value 2’, … ‘value10]}     
    send_to_slack('My test message from python')

default_args = {... 
'on_failure_callback': send_to_slack, }

with DAG(‘my_dag’,
         default_args=default_args,
         catchup=False) as dag:
    parallel = 4
    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    tasks = []
    i = 0
    for s in x.keys():
        for t in x.get(s):
            task = OracleToSnowflakeOperator(                
                task_id=s + '_' + t,
                source_oracle_conn_id=source_oracle_conn_id,
                source_schema=schema,
                source_table=table,…
            )
            if i <= parallel:
                task.set_upstream(start)
            else:
                task.set_upstream(tasks[i - (parallel + 1)])
            i = i + 1
            tasks.append(task)
```

I know if I define the function inside the same dag, it will be called every time the dag is parsed.
not my case, so What's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What are you calling to run this?

Comment: @alireza-tajadod you mean with my dag...
with dag('my_dag')?

Comment: Your code example seams to be incomplete. Please add more from the dag part, e.g. any kind of loop structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the function `send_to_slack` inside your DAG file, this means it will run every time the scheduler evaluates your DAG (every few minutes).

You should either:

- Use the [slack operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/slack/operators/slack.py) that comes with Airflow and put it downstream from your `OracleToSnowflakeOperator` and treat it like any other operator
- Edit your `OracleToSnowflakeOperator`, which I assume is a custom one, and put the logic to call Slack in there (use the slack hook)

Basically you should put be encapsulating the call to Slack inside a custom operator or use the standard Slack operator provided, don't put it inside your DAG definition.

Comment: Thanks @SimonD this worked fine. I just modified the logic in OracleToSnowflakeOperator